# Bouncing scroll

Tags: plugins

Morning,

I am developing a wordpress site for an online PT. I am using the elementor builder and have used a price table module.

On desktop, the page works fine. On mobile chrome when I scroll down to the pricing table and scroll up and down, the scroll seems to twitch and bounce.

Any ideas?

http://s769027911.websitehome.co.uk/online-training/

Comment: I don't notice any unusual twitches or bounces on my device (Chrome on Android).

Comment: Are you using smooth scroll?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you both for the advice.

I have checked and it's my phone browser. I'm using a modified version of chrome called Kiwi, which allows plugins. It's most likely a plugin conflict not a website issue.